# mat-datepicker shows wrong calendar in format MMM d

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a datepicker input field in Angular material that is of the format `MMM d`. Now I want to set the calendar to stick to the year 2020 as it shows even the leap year date of Feb 29. I have managed to limit the `max` & `min` of the input and set a default date of `Jan 1`. But somehow the datepicker is picking wrong dates from the selected date in the calendar and is also showing **0** as a possible date.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-date-picker?file=src/app/datepicker1/datepicker1.component.html)

Any help is appreciated.

**Template:**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (dateChange)="change($event)" [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="Verbose datepicker" [formControl]="date"
  [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate" [value]="setDefault()">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { MomentDateAdapter } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";
import {
  DateAdapter,
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
  MAT_DATE_LOCALE
} from "@angular/material";
import * as _moment from "moment";
import { default as _rollupMoment } from "moment";
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: "MMM d"
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: "MMM d",
    monthYearLabel: "MMM d",
    dateA11yLabel: "LL",
    monthYearA11yLabel: "MMMM d"
  }
};

@Component({
  selector: "app-datepicker1",
  templateUrl: "./datepicker1.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./datepicker1.component.css"],
  providers: [
    DatePipe,
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]
    },

    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }
  ]
})
export class Datepicker1Component implements OnInit {
  @Output() date1: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  date = new FormControl(moment());

  minDate = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
  maxDate = new Date(2020, 11, 31);

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  change(dateEvent) {
    this.date1.emit(dateEvent.value);
  }

  setDefault() {
    let d = new Date("2020-01-01");
    console.log(this.datePipe.transform(d, "MMM d"));
    return this.datePipe.transform(d, "MMM d");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `d` is for the day of the week, 0 being sunday, 1 being monday, until 6 which is saturday, you'll need to fix that, for the day of the month you need `D`.

It should be:

```js
display: {
  dateInput: "MMM D",
  //...           ^
}
```

And fix the other fields accordingly, of course.